# Ensure JavaScript fetches from Disk Cache

Tags: javascript, http-caching

I have an AJAX-based application which consists of the following pages:

```
home.html --> browse_projects.html --> view_project.html
```

In `home.html`, I fetch a script as follows:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

After fetching `materialize.min.js`, I can see that the browser caches this.

Now, `browse_projects.html` also happens to require `materialize.min.js`.
So, I include it like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

However, while running some tests, I notice that the browser does not retrieve it from the cache. Rather, it gets a new copy with an URL such as:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js?_=1490644754909
```

Now, my question is - Why doesn't it retrieve the cached copy? How can I enforce this?

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is not getting cached in your tests is this: `_=1490644754909` - a random number is appended to the URL. Browsers cache static assets based upon the URL, if the URL changes every time, the browser will not cache the asset (aka: "cache busting"). If you are not using a templating library that can append the random string to the URL inline, you could load the scripts using Javascript instead:

```
<script>
function loadScript(src) {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = script.src + '?_=' + (+new Date());
   document.head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js');
</script>
```

This will append a random number to the end of your URL to prevent browser caching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, I'm confused.. I don't want to prevent browser caching. In fact, I want to use the cached version of `materialize.min.js`. By adding a random number at the end aren't we preventing that?

Comment: The question was how to enforce caching not how to cache bust.